# localization of items and groups in vis.js timeline

Tags: localization, timeline, vis.js

We used vis.js to create a  timeline , We need to localize the name of groups and the content of items with different languages . we tried to use the $translate = $filter('translate') to translate the name of group in angularjs but it works only when we reloading the screen . We also tried for the translation of items to use the template handlebars engine to translate the items but The problem is that Angular seems not to proceed the templates used by Handlebars when we put "{{ 'timeline.content' | translate }} it gives an error . so is there any idea or a way  to localize name of groups and items in vis.js .

Answer (score 0):

You can use the configuration functions ***groupTemplate*** or ***template***

```
var config = {
  ...
  groupTemplate: function (group) {
    var groupTemplate = document.createElement('div');
    // assuming that you have stored the label key in the content, instead of text.
    groupTemplate.innerText = translate.get(group.content);
    // or whatever function call you need to make to get the translated label;
    return groupTemplate;
    }
  ...
  }
```

You can do the same with the actual items in the timeline.

```
var config = {
  ...
  template: function (item) {
    var itemTemplate = document.createElement('div');
    // assuming that you have stored the labels in the content, instead of text.
    itemTemplate.innerText = translate.get(item.content) 
    // or whatever function call you need to make to get the translated label;
    return itemTemplate;
    }
  ...
  }
```

You can also attach event listeners, or do whatever with templates as they render to a usual DOM elements.

Hope this helps.